# Pause slide show to load more images

Tags: highslide

I have an image gallery that uses infinite scroll to load its images. When I start a slide show on an image, when its reached the end of the currently loaded images, it wraps around and starts at the beginning.

What I would like to have happen is that it pauses, loads the next set of content and then continues the slide show through the new images.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible without some extensive rewriting of the script. See my answer in the regular Highslide JS forum:

http://forum.highcharts.com/highslide-js-usage/pause-slide-show-to-load-more-images-t32983/